# Rename of Multiple files by command or software

Tags: command-line, files

I have many files for that i want to rename them.

Current Name: `5b011351286e8a042b23ffff\5b011351286e8a042b23ffff_130225_145634.xml`

Required Name: `5b011351286e8a042b23ffff_130225_145634.xml`

I just want to delete the part before the backslash and the forward slash as well.

I have 500 files for which i want to do same.

Comment: Wait, you said forward slash, but your example file name contains only backslashes.

Comment: @muru I guess both may occurred in the list

Comment: Sorry its backslash

Comment: Duplicate of [How to batch rename files with "variables"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72628/how-to-batch-rename-files-with-variables) and [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350686/how-to-rename-multiple-files) and [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/301781/how-to-rename-multiple-files-sequentially-from-command-line)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
rename -n 's;.*\\;;s' *.xml
```

If the results are what you want, run it again without `-n`.
To open a terminal press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>. Navigate to your Desktop folder:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

Then run the first command. You'll get a response like this:

```
5b011351286e8a042b23ffff\5b011351286e8a042b23ffff_130225_145634.xml renamed as 5b011351286e8a042b23ffff_130225_145634.xml
```

And a lot of other lines for all the files matching the conditions. If you're satisfied with the output, then run:

```
rename 's;.*\\;;s' *.xml
```

---

Explanation:

1. `rename` is a Perl program (and hence which accepts Perl expressions) for renaming files. The `-n` option will tell `rename` to show what it will do, without actually doing anything.
2. The Perl expression `s;.*\\;;s` means `s`ubsitute for all characters (`.*`) followed by one backslash (`\\` - it needs to escaped, since `\` has a special meaning) with nothing (the `;` divides each section of the expression) while treating the entire input as a single `s`tring.

Comment: Pls i want to do it in ubuntu terminal.

Comment: @Yameen the command is to be run in a terminal.

Comment: i am a beginner level user of ubuntu i don't understand this command can you pls help in details. I have these files on my desktop in folder.

Comment: @Yameen That will take a while, and I'm on a phone now. I think you should comment on Sylvain's answer for a quicker response.

Comment: @Yameen have a look now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rename` command:

```
rename 's/^.*[\\\/]//s' *.xml
```

Comment: thanks @muru. I put `^` to match filenames beginning like this. Other than that, 100% agree with your proposal :). You have my vote as well for the `-n` option

Comment: Does the `^` matter? With a `.*` and greedy matching, it shouldn't be needed, right? Is there some corner case I'm missing?

Comment: @muru Actually it will allow `rename` to work with files containing a newline character. I know it's a bit crazy but otherwise you'll get `Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /usr/bin/rename line 59.`

Comment: Ah. I modified my answer to handle that using the `s` modifier.

Comment: I was about to do the same :) ... and I cannot vote twice!

Answer (score 1):

If the length of you file name is same(till the part you want to change) for all the file in this case you can do it easily with the help of  **Thunar Bulk Rename**   which comes with Thunar file manager.

Install it using `sudo apt-get install thunar`

Now open  Bullk Rename from Dash. It has various option for how you want to rename your file.
In you case I have create a file with the name you have give, adjusted few parameter and renamed it. 
[image]

Comment: HI g_p  Thanks for the wonderful reply. May i have the linux coding for only this logic..which is mentioned like remove from the position 24 and to position 49. I want to make a separate GUI application.

Comment: see `cut` command. the logic for above may be `echo $filename | cut -c24-49`

Comment: How to make a GUI application for this type of output dear g_P..

Comment: It is broad topic. If you want to make gui application in c++ , you can use QtCreator.

Comment: can you pls create a application for me and i want just this output. I want to run this application in ubuntu 12.04 . Kindly i have request.

Comment: Sorry buddy. Here we provide support for Ubuntu. But writing  a simple application would be really easy. First try yourself.